# Research methodology in formal verification

Tags: proof-assistant

Is there a written account on how to carry out research in formal verification with proof assistants?

Formalisation of standard mathematics, verification of information systems and developing proof assistants, theoretically and practically would be interesting. And if you have an idea beyond these, that also.

Comment: I do not understand what an answer would constitute, so I am tentatively blaming the question. To make my point, I find your question equivalent to "is there a written account on how to do zoology?"

Comment: Are you looking for an introductory textbook on formalizing of math?